# The plural 等 in おいら, おら

Tags: etymology, first-person-pronouns, plurals

Why do the singular first person pronouns 俺{おい}等{ら} and 俺{お}等{ら} involve the plural affix 等?

[image] [image]

Comment: Interesting. EDICT shows 「おら」 as 「己」.

Comment: That is probably ateji. And that source is highly unreliable.

Comment: このサイト見てる大半の人は写真の意味わからないんだろうな、きっと。

Comment: Well, even if you learn the language, a lot of cultural references will go over your head.

Comment: Tohoku's "ora" is singular, and written 俺 in kanji. I don't know why you think it's plural. Moreover, I don't see why you post Yoshi Ikuzo's picture either: he song "おら東京さ行ぐだ" is about a single person, not a group.  FWIW, all my Tohoku-ben speaking friends and I say "おらたち" (or rather, おらたづ) when using plural.

Comment: @Axioplase I am assuming that in present (Tohoku) Japanese, semantically, it is used as singular, but etymologically, it involves the plural affix. It is not rare in languages that a morpheme loses its original meaning and later require another morpheme to further add the same meaning. So I do not think that おらたづ is an evidence that ら was not plural originally (although it may be that it lost the plural meaning by now).

Comment: @sawa-san, 吉幾三さんの「♪東京でベコ飼うだ~~」は分かります。でもビートたけしさんの方は・・・分かりません。どちらかというとこの人の方がなじみがあるかも→ http://img5.blogs.yahoo.co.jp/ybi/1/d5/d5/osamiya0817/folder/1207774/img_1207774_35438231_0?1304395290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I am not sure that /ora/ really belongs in this category. Most dictionaries simply list it as a variant of /ore/. But /oira/ is pretty unanimously agreed to derive from /orera/, 俺 + 等 as you say, so I will stick to discussion of that one. (In any case, presumably whatever applies to /oira/ would also apply to /ora/ if indeed they were the same /-ra/.)

So, the key point is that 等 does not necessarily mean "[+plural]" in a literal sense. In the case of /oira/ it was originally a way of expressing non-specificness and therefore humbleness. Contemporary first-person singular usages like /watakusi.domo/ and /watakusi nado/ are, I think, an example of the same phenomenon: they don't mean "myself and others", but rather "(a lowly) one such as myself". You can find this usage attached to other pronouns too in historical documents; the Kojien has an example of first-person singular /ware.ra/ for example. And of course it has also been attached to second- or third-person pronouns to express contempt (something like the contemporary /omae  nado/).