# What is the meaning of "おいらの中では" in this tweet?

Tags: phrases

I just saw this tweet:

> **おいらの中では、** 何年か前にISISから改名したISについて、すぐにISへ呼び方を変えたBBCと、ISISと呼び続けるCNNというイメージなので、CNNがIslamic Stateと呼ぶのを見て驚{おどろ}いてる。

I would translate:

> With regard to changing the name of ISIS to IS a few years ago, I had the impression that the BBC immediately started saying IS while CNN continued to say ISIS. Therefore, I am surprised to see that CNN is now calling them "Islamic State".

ok. I just learned that "オイラ" is slang for a first-person pronoun.

- I am reading "おいらの中では、" to just mean "私は" because of [this definition](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/5432/meaning/m0u/). But, surely it means something more than that.
- In the Twittersphere, brevity trumps all else. With the ending verb being "を見て驚いてる", that this is written from a first-person point of view is obvious. Why cannot "おいらの中では、" just be implied? There must be significant meaning in that phrase?

and here is the link to the tweet:
[actual tweet](https://twitter.com/YamakenIC/status/844932415713787905)

Comment: Can you link us to the tweet?

Comment: @Nothingatall ok. I added a direct link in my question at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `person + の中では` is a common (but more or less slangy) way to say "in one's understanding" or "from what one understands". Here, it's used to imply the following part (すぐにISへ呼び方を変えたBBCとISISと呼び続けるCNNというイメージ) is not something confirmed but only his understanding. ～というイメージ implies the same thing, so you can drop this おいらの中では without significantly changing the meaning of the sentence. But, as you know, 140 Japanese characters is much "longer" than 140 English characters. Your translation seems fine to me.

Comment: I totally agree that "brevity is the soul of Japanese." That's why I like the language so much. Indeed, you sure can say a lot more in 140 Japanese characters!

Answer (score 0):

おいら is a shift from おれら, which is おれ (first-person masculine very-informal singular pronoun) + ら (pluralizer).  So おいら is not (roughly) equivalent to 私は, but rather to 私達, where the speaker is male and the social context is in-group.  The verb ending alone does not give us this context regarding the speaker and audience.

#### Update

While I had learned おいら as a plural, and the term おいら is listed in many dictionaries as deriving from おれ + ら, it seems I may have either learned a dialectal variation in meaning, or simply misunderstood something along the way.  Please refer to naruto's answer.

Comment: "おいら" means "おれ", "僕", "私". So, "おれら" is what you are saying. "おいらら" is not correct. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/5432/meaning/m0u/

Comment: おいら is singular.  This answer makes no sense.

Comment: I had been taught that おいら was plural.  Perhaps 東北弁?  Or did I just get the wrong end of the stick somewhere?

Comment: このスレッドが参考になるかも？　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6408/9831

Comment: 語源は知りませんが、現代の使われ方としては単数だと思います。

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi maybe you were thinking of 俺等達 [おいらっち (oiratchi)] ?